# Handling Invoice Number in Multiple Computer

Tags: java, database, invoice

I am developing billing software in java. In my application user opens a window for creating an invoice.

When the window opens it fetchs the `MaxID` and returns a `long` `MaxID+1`  from the `INVOICE` table and displays it in a `Jlabel`. Now when user starts billing everytime the invoice number will be `MaxID+1`. This system runs fine in single user application.

But when this application runs in multiple computer a great issue happens. When Two users, say, `userOne` and `userTwo` opens the same window at the same time they will get the same `MaxID+1`. and as a result Both of them will enter data in the same invoice number. How can I resolve this?

Please help.

Comment: Also is there any reason you are not using Auto increment column in DB itself?

Comment: Auto increment will not work here, because the MaxID+1 will be same for several rows. It's the invoice id. One invoice can have multiple items.

Answer (score 1):

Classical scenario of Race Condition. You need to Synchronize the access to MaxId. Based on your database you need to lock the `Invoice` table before accessing the MaxId and unlock it once you retrieve it. The retrieval of MaxId must be atomic.

Comment: Probably best to do that syncronization in a stored proceedure on the DB which does the MaxID+1 update and returns the value, then have your application call that proceedure to get the next ID. That allows for totally separate instances of the application to co-exist.